# List Comprehension Instead of Nested For Loops for Repeated Number List

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I want to create a script that creates a list of values between two variables `(First_Number, Last_Number)` where each number repeats `Repeat_Count` times. I wrote a script that has nested `for` loops to do this. I would like to do this with list comprehension, but don't know if it's possible.

```
First_Number = 1
Last_Number = 10
Repeat_Count = 5

MyList = []
for numbers in range(First_Number,Last_Number - First_Number + 2):
    for repeated_number in range(0,Repeat_Count):
        MyList.append(numbers)

print MyList
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: What's the logic behind `Last_Number - First_Number + 2`? Should it be `Last_Number + 1`?

Comment: @yoel, its because I want to include 'Last_Number' and because I start the range at 1 not 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
[x for x in xrange(First_Number, Last_Number+1) for y in xrange(Repeat_Count)]
```

Comment: should probably use xrange for python2

Comment: @PadraicCunningham can you explain why?

Comment: @user2242044, range creates a list in memory, xrange returns an xrange object which is basically a generator so you generate numbers as you go not all at once.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain(*[[i]*repeat_count for i in range(first_number, last_number+1)]))
```

`chain` will flatten arrays: `[[1, 1], [2, 2]] => [1, 1, 2, 2]`

`[i]*repeat_count` is a nice way to generate `[i, i, i, ... , i]`

Also, it's a general rule to name variables lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in an pythonic way

```
>>> first_num = 1
>>> last_num = 10
>>> repeat_no = 5
>>> mylist = []
>>> [mylist.extend([num]*repeat_no) for num in range(first_num, last_num + 1)]
>>> mylist
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: I think you mean unpythonic

Comment: @PadraicCunningham you should tell me why?

Comment: list comps should be used to hold values, using it like this  is not pythonic.